Apple Store connect pipeline - artefacts
I'm placed some tests using Appium in the pipeline to run post build.
To get a better understanding of the failures I have set up a video recording of the simulator device, but I don't know where should I save it to be then downloaded after the run?
First of all, is it possible to save something like screenshots, or video recording?
If it's possible, what is the path that I should use for that?
Or am I going at this from the wrong direction? Is there a better way of recording the issue in details?
This is the standard path for the build
/Volumes/workspace/DerivedData

Your question is missing what CI you are using, is it jenkins or something else? Where are you running the appium tests?

Maybe it wasn't clear @mosaad
It's Apple Store Connect, it's in the title?
So before publishing the app on the store, there's steps like build, tests and so on.
It's managed by Apple, so I don't really have ideas on where to save the artefacts.
